# Return Value of None?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem on CodeWars with the following specifications:

"Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit."

My solution is as follows:

```
def persistence(n,count = 0):
    n = list(str(n))
    if len(n)  <= 1 :
        count = 0
        return count
    else :
        num_per = 1
        for i in n :
            num_per = num_per * int(i)
        num_dump = num_per
        if len(str(num_dump)) > 1:
            count += 1
            n = num_per
            persistence(n,count)
        else:
            count = count + 1
            return count
```

When I choose any number with more than a single digit, I get a return value of 'None'. I've narrowed down the problem to the last return statement in the second else clause. The number of counts are calculated correctly,but the return statement still returns a value of 'None'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're getting the `None` from falling off the end of the function, rather than any of your explicit `return` statements.

Comment: No, you need to return the result of your recursive call, like any other function call

Comment: Change the line to `return persistence(n,count)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add return before your persistence line:

```
return persistence(n, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of what @jasonharper suggested, your function has an **if/else** statement which is decided by **len(n) <= 1**. If the length of **n** is less than 1, **count** (which is 0) is returned.

In your **else** statement however, you have another **if/else** statement. In your **if** statement, which is decided by **len(str(num_dump)) > 1**, you decide to recursively call the same function, however, you return no value. Therefore, your program most likely makes a lot of recursive calls but has no way of storing the values to be returned at the end of the program.

This can be fixed by replacing

> persistence(n, count)

with

> return persistence(n, count)